# Post sales order to 3rd party api with reply

Tags: magento

Basically I'm trying to send sales orders to third-party API from magento and receive a notification whether the order has been accepted or not.
I have created users and rolls for the rest system with api user and password And I have read multiple Forum posts but can't seem to find where to go from here I have a piece of code which I've been given by the third- API to connect to their API here is the info below

```
Post example (fixed)    
<form method="post" action="http://iconnect.ibacstel.com/submitorder.php">
<input name="api_key" value="Your API Key" />
<input name="api_password" value="Your API Password" />
<input name="notify_url" value="Notify URL" /> <!-Notify url is your websites url where you would like to get notification from ibacstel api -->
<input name="receipt_header" value="Header Line1%%123 Street Address, City, Zip Code" />
<input name="receipt_footer" value="Thanks for your custom..." />
<input name="printer_id" value="Your printer ID" />
<input name="order_id" value="OrderID" />
<input name="currency" value="Currency" /><!--ex. USD/GBP -->
<input name="order_type" value="1" /><!--Delivery=1, Pick up=2, Reservation=3-->
<input name="payment_status" value="6" /><!--Paid=6, Not Paid=7-->
<input name="payment_method" value="Payment Method" />
<input name="delivery_time" value="18:30 17-09-10 " /><!--Format=HH:MM DD-MM-YY-->
<input name="auth_code" value="Payment authorization code" />

<input name="cat_1" value="Category 1" />
<input name="item_1" value="Item Name 1" />
<input name="desc_1" value="Item description 1" />
<input name="qnt_1" value="1" />
<input name="price_1" value="10.50" />

<input name="cat_2" value="" />
<input name="item_2" value="Item Name 2" />
<input name="desc_2" value="Item description 2" />
<input name="qnt_2" value="1" />
<input name="price_2" value="10.50" />

<input name="cat_3" value="Category 2" />
<input name="item_3" value="Item Name 3" />
<input name="desc_3" value="Item description 3" />
<input name="qnt_3" value="1" />
<input name="price_3" value="10.50" />

---------
You can place more items here using above format.
Please note that you don't need to send category name for the items after first item if the category name is same and if you put all same category items consecutively.
---------
<input name="deliverycost" value="3.50" />
<input name="card_fee" value="0.50" />
<input name="extra_fee" value="1.50" />
<input name="total_discount" value="4.50" />
<input name="total_amount" value="56.50" /><!--Grand Total -->
<input name="cust_name" value="Customer Name" />
<input name="cust_address" value="Customer address" />
<input name="cust_phone" value="Phone number" />
<input name="cust_instruction" value="Special instruction" />
<input name="isVarified" value="4" /><!-Verified=4, Not verified=5 -->
<input name="num_prev_order" value="Number of previous order" />
---------settings---------
<input name="apply_settings " value="1" />
<input name="auto_print" value="1" />
<input name="auto_accept" value="1" />
<input name="enter_delivery_time" value="1" />
<input name="time_input_method" value="2" />
<input name="time_list" value="0-5-10-15-20-25-30-35-40-45-50-55-60" />
<input name="extra_line_feed" value="3" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


Post example (free style)   
<form method="post" action="http://iconnect.ibacstel.com/submitorderfreestyle.php">
<input name="api_key" value="Your API Key" />
<input name="api_password" value="Your API Password" />
<input name="notify_url" value="Notify URL" /> <!-Notify url is your websites url where you would like to get notification from ibacstel api -->
<input name="receipt_header" value="Header Line1%%123 Street Address, City, Zip Code" />
<input name="receipt_footer" value="Thanks for your custom..." />
<input name="printer_id" value="Your printer ID" />
<input name="order_id" value="OrderID" />
<input name="currency" value="Currency" /><!--ex. USD/GBP -->
<input name="delivery_time" value="18:30 17-09-10 " /><!--Format=HH:MM DD-MM-YY-->
<input name="print_data" value="Line 1/rLine 2%%Line 3/-" />
<input name="total_amount" value="56.50" /><!--Grand Total -->
---------settings---------
<input name="apply_settings " value="1" />
<input name="auto_print" value="1" />
<input name="print_only" value="0" />
<input name="auto_accept" value="1" />
<input name="enter_delivery_time" value="1" />
<input name="time_input_method" value="2" />
<input name="time_list" value="0-5-10-15-20-25-30-35-40-45-50-55-60" />
<input name="extra_line_feed" value="3" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


Success response    
<response>
   <status>OK</status>
   <details>
      <msg>Order has been stored successfully</msg>
   </details>
</response>


Error response  
<response>
   <status>FAILED</status>
   <details>
      <error> Authentication failed </error>
      <error> Other errors...</error>
   </details>
</response>


Update notification format  
When printer sends a callback response to API the API sends a notification to the Provided Notify URL with order
In your notification url you will get notification regarding the status of the order, all the information will be submitted via post method which will allow you to grab information easily.

Post variables:
"printer_id" = Printer ID
"order_id" = Order ID
"status" = (1=accepted,2=rejected)
"msg" = message from printer
"delivery_time" = confirmed delivery time from printer
"manual_update" = (1=manual update identifier)
"booking" = (1=manage booking identifier)

Please note that you will not get the notification while you are sending order to API even if the notify URL is same as where you are sending order to API. API will send response later automatically when the order will be accepted/rejected from printer to that Notify URL you provided with order. So we recommend you to use separate URL/file to send order to API and receive notification from API to avoid confusion.

Example in PHP

Lets say you are sending order the URL of your site www.example.com/sendorder.php to API
So you need to write necessary code on sendorder.php to send order information from your site to API. I am not telling you the details here how to send order to API. Please check our example html form above to send order information to API.
Lets say you have used the value of notification URL field www.example.com/receivenotification.php in orders sending form like <input name="notify_url" value="www.example.com/receivenotification.php" /> then iConnect API will send notification to www.example.com/receivenotification.php as soon as API get response from printer when an order will be accepted/rejected after printing. Here is the example code to grab the information from API notification need to be placed on receivenotification.php file.
<?php

$printer_id = $_REQUEST['printer_id'];
$order_id = $_REQUEST['order_id'];
$order_status = $_REQUEST['status'];
$message = $_REQUEST['msg'];
$delivery_time = $_REQUEST['delivery_time'];

if($order_status==1){
   //order has been accepted from printer
   //do your necessary task for accepted order like update databse, send email to customer to inform him that his order has been accepted and will be delivered on returned delivery time (variable $delivery_time).
}
else{
   //order has been rejected from printer
   //do your necessary task for rejected order like update databse, send email to customer to inform him that his order has been rejected for the returned reason (variable $message).
}

?>
```

Basically I need to know where to put this code and or what file I have to modify or create in order to do this. Thanks in advance

So i have created all of the files that you detailed out and i have put my 3rd party code where you stated it to go but, isnt working, heree is my thirdparty.php file contents maybee you will se where im going wrong.

```
<?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Thirdparty {

    public function automatic(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
        {
            $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
            if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
             return;
             }
            foreach($orderIds as $eachOrderId){
                 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($eachOrderId);
                <form method="post" action="http://iconnect.ibacstel.com/submitorderfreestyle.php">
<input name="api_key" value="******" />
<input name="api_password" value="************" />
<input name="notify_url" value="Notify URL" /> <!-Notify url is your websites url where you would like to get notification from ibacstel api -->
<input name="receipt_header" value="Header Line1%%Take, City, Zip Code" />
<input name="receipt_footer" value="Thanks for your custom..." />
<input name="printer_id" value="Your printer ID" />
<input name="order_id" value="OrderID" />
<input name="currency" value="Currency" /><!--ex. USD/GBP -->
<input name="delivery_time" value="18:30 17-09-10 " /><!--Format=HH:MM DD-MM-YY-->
<input name="print_data" value="Line 1/rLine 2%%Line 3/-" />
<input name="total_amount" value="56.50" /><!--Grand Total -->
---------settings---------
<input name="apply_settings " value="1" />
<input name="auto_print" value="1" />
<input name="print_only" value="0" />
<input name="auto_accept" value="1" />
<input name="enter_delivery_time" value="1" />
<input name="time_input_method" value="2" />
<input name="time_list" value="0-5-10-15-20-25-30-35-40-45-50-55-60" />
<input name="extra_line_feed" value="3" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


Success response    
<response>
   <status>OK</status>
   <details>
      <msg>Order has been stored successfully</msg>
   </details>
</response>


Error response  
<response>
   <status>FAILED</status>
   <details>
      <error> Authentication failed </error>
      <error> Other errors...</error>
   </details>
</response>


            }
            return $this;
        }


}
```

is this correct? also can you please take a look at the third party code and tell me weather this will work in magento or do i have to translate this into a different language? Thankks

Answer (score 2):

Magento have an interesting feature Event-obsever and trigger and run some code using observer.
For example,nagento event list http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/
for frontend after place an  order run some 
Create an extension  using

**create config.xml under app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/etc**

```
           <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
                <class>Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model</class>
                </zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
                            </models>

        </global>
        <frontend>
            <events>

                <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                    <observers>
                        <create_thridparty_order>
                            <class>zerosubtotalpaymentmethod/thirdparty</class>
                            <method>automatic</method>
                        </create_thridparty_order>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>

            </events>
        </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
            <events>

                <checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <observers>
                        <create_thridparty_order>
                            <class>zerosubtotalpaymentmethod/thirdparty</class>
                            <method>automatic</method>
                        </create_thridparty_order>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_submit_all_after>

            </events>
        </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**** And then create Thirdparty.php under app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/Model/**

```
<?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Thirdparty {

public function automatic(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($orderIds as $eachOrderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($eachOrderId);
        //right our third party code
        client = new Zend_Http_Client();
        $client->setUri('http://iconnect.ibacstel.com/submitorderfreestyle.php');
        $client->>setParameterPost(array(
        'api_key' => 'yourapi',
        'apikey' => 'xxxx',
        'message' => $message,
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        ...//more params
        ));
        $response = $client->request('POST');
        // Yet another way of preforming a POST request
        $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);

        if (!$response->isSuccessful()) {
            Mage::log($response);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

}
```

**Also.create under  Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod.xml
app/etc/modules/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
</modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply, so i have to create the two files but where do i put my rest api details for magento api, and am i right in saying that (//right our third party code) is where i place the code that i posted erlier? Thanks

Comment: Ok tanks so much i am in the middle of testing these out now and will let you know the outcome. Would you happen to know the notify url URL to where you want to be notified about order accept/reject from printer. Thanks so much for the help i have een goin over this for weeks

Comment: Hi there I have created the files and have edited my original post and placed my thirdparty.php file there so you can see it, I still can't seem to figure out where my rest user and roll come into the equation, could you point me in the right direction as to how I give permission for the 3rd party api to reply to the magento as to weather the order has been accepted or rejected

Comment: Can somebody give me some guidance on how to actuall make this work please. Thank You

Comment: Works even when we use Express Paypal checkout. (Y) +1 MAN!